# Random ultrametric trees

Tags: python, cluster-analysis, phylogeny

I've implemented a program on python which generates random binary trees. So now I'd like to assign to each internal node of the tree a distance to make it ultrametric. Then, the distance between the root and any leaves must be the same. If a node is a leaf then the distance is null. Here is a node :

```
class Node() :
    def __init__(self, G = None , D = None) :
        self.id = ""
        self.distG = 0
        self.distD = 0
        self.G = G
        self.D = D
        self.parent = None
```

My idea is to set the distance h at the beginning and to decrease it as an internal node is found but its working only on the left side.

```
def lgBrancheRand(self, h) :
    self.distD = h
    self.distG = h
    hrandomD = round(np.random.uniform(0,h),3)
    hrandomG = round(np.random.uniform(0,h),3)
    if self.D.D is not None :
        self.D.distD = hrandomD
        self.distD = round(h-hrandomD,3)
        lgBrancheRand(self.D,hrandomD)
    if self.G.G is not None :
        self.G.distG = hrandomG
        self.distG = round(h-hrandomG,3)
        lgBrancheRand(self.G,hrandomG)
```

Comment: A) don't assume everybody knows what an ultrametric tree is. Define it for those 99.9% of users that don't. B) distances are usually defined between two points. So you should explain the semantics that you expect from these values. C) the usual approach would be a bottom-up construction, rather than top-down, I assume.

Answer (score 1):

In summary, you would create random matrices and apply UPGMA to each.

**More complete answer below**

Simply use the UPGMA algorithm. This is a clustering algorithm used to resolve a pairwise matrix.

You take the total genetic distance between two pairs of "taxa" (technically OTUs) and divide it by two. You assign the closest members of the pairwise matrix as the first 'node'. Reformat the matrix so these two pairs are combined into a single group ('removed') and find the next 'nearest neighbor' ad infinitum. I suspect R 'ape' will have a ultrametric algorhithm which will save you from programming. I see that you are using Python, so BioPython MIGHT have this (big MIGHT), personally I would pipe this through a precompiled C program and collect the results via paup that sort of thing. I'm not going to write code, because I prefer Perl and get flamed if any Perl code appears in a Python question (the Empire has established).

Anyway you will find this algorhithm produces a perfect ultrametric tree. Purests do not like ultrametric trees derived throught this sort of algorithm. However, in your calculation it could be useful because you could find the phylogeny from real data , which is most "clock-like" against the null distribution you are producing. In this context it would be cool.

---

You might prefer to raise the question on bioinformatics stackexchange.